# Room database search in comma separated string

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

In my sqlite database I have column like following

```
**Cities**
------------------------
new york, chicago, boston
London, bristorl , leeds, boston
```

Now if I search with keywords like "boston" , it will return both first and second row, if I search with chicago, it will return only first row .

This is what I have tried

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM TableName" + " WHERE + :city IN (Cities) ")
List<UserInfo> getAllByCities(String city);
```

but it is not working , it is returning nothing .

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You can try with `" WHERE  Cities IN (:city) ")`. You write wrong query. And what is your `TableName`, do you replace the real table?

Comment: Yes , I replaced . I tried it but it didn't return anything :(

Comment: You can try again with `%:city%`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below table for demo purposes.

CSVColumn

```
a,b
a,b,c
a
b
c
a,c
```

Contains

```
select * from mytable where '1' = dbo.fun_QueryCSVColumn (CSVColumn,',','a','contains')
```

output the below table find the **a** value:

```
a,b
a,b,c
a
a,c
```

Contains

`select * from mytable where '1' = dbo.fun_QueryCSVColumn (CSVColumn,',','b,a','contains')`

output the below table find the **b,a** value:

```
a,b
a,b,c
a
b
a,c
```

Contains

```
select * from mytable where '1' = dbo.fun_QueryCSVColumn  (CSVColumn,',','c','contains')
```

output the below table find the **c** value:

```
a,c
a,b,c
```

i think it helps you.

Comment: Thanks , but my database is not csv file